# Why is this just printing my array instead of doing the math and printing out the finished math?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math

I'm trying to get this to take the same number from within an array (newSideList) and multiply them together thus squaring them as the sum I am trying to use is s^2*n/(4*tan(180/n)). However when i run the code, it seems to have done some math within the array and I have no idea what or why. Please could someone explain.

The rest of the top half works as i've run it without this math part, it just doesn't seem to perform this calculation properly.

```html
import math
import numpy as np
sideList = []


numOfSides = int(input("How many sides does your shape have? "))

for i in range(0,numOfSides):
 lengths = str(input("Please input the length of each side individually: "))
 sideList.append(lengths)
 
processSideList = np.array([sideList])
newSideList = processSideList.astype(np.float)

def areaCalcReg():
 area = newSideList[0] * newSideList[0] * numOfSides / 4 * math.tan(180/numOfSides)
 print(area)




#def areaCalcIrreg():






#def perimCalc():


decision = str(input("Is this a regular or irregular shape?\nType an R for regular or I for irregular: "))

if decision == "R" or decision == "r":
 areaCalcReg()

#elif decision == "I" or decision == "i":
  #areaCalcIrreg()

#else: 
 #if decision != "R" and decision !="r" and decision != "I" and decision != "i": 
  #print("Please pick either an R for regular or an I for irregular.\n")
  #return()
```

Ignore the # out parts, they are a work in progress, just want to get this sorted before continuing with the rest of the program.

I'm hoping that the program will perform the sum and give an output of 1 number, which will be the area of the shape that has been inputted by the user. Here is the input and output from the program:

Input:

How many sides does your shape have? 4
Please input the length of each side individually: 2.2
Please input the length of each side individually: 3.3
Please input the length of each side individually: 4.4
Please input the length of each side individually: 5
Is this a regular or irregular shape?
Type an R for regular or I for irregular: r

Output:

[ 7.83971192 17.63935183 31.35884769 40.49437976]

Why is this the result and how do i fix it?

Comment: What _should_ the output be given the inputs you've provided?

Comment: Are you aware of math.tan using radians and not degree angle? 180 degrees equals pi radians

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1) The trigonometry functions use radians, i.e., you should use

```
math.tan(math.pi/numOfSides)
```

2) You are multiplying by the tangent because you are missing a pair of parentheses

```
area = newSideList[0] * newSideList[0] * numOfSides / (4 * math.tan(math.pi/numOfSides))
```

Comment: i've done that and now i get an output of: [ 1.7204774   6.8819096  15.48429661 27.52763841 43.01193501] from the inputs: 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 and 5

Comment: And you expected something different?

Comment: i'm trying to get it to use the first item of the array and do the calculation using that, then print out 1 number that will be the area of the given shape

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you are only interested in the first number?